# What characters will PreparedStatement escape?

Tags: java, jdbc

I noticed that when I use a `PreparedStatement` it doesn't seem to escape certain wild-card characters like '%' or '_'. I know these can be escaped in MySql using a backslash. This made me wonder, what characters will a `PreparedStatement` escape?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`PreparedStatement` doesn't escape anything - it relies on database support for precompiled statements.

That is, `PreparedStatement` never substitutes `?`s for parameter values in order to form a literal query string. Instead, it sends a query string with placeholders to the database and uses database support to bind query parameters (however, it may depend on JDBC driver implementation).

Comment: Interesting, what does that support look like for MySql?

Comment: MySql supports prepared statements in the same way on the server side.  How it looks in your code depends on the driver you are using.

Comment: I believe many drivers actually do insert escaped argument text into the SQL text.

Comment: @stevebot: Quick googling showed this: http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/4.1/prepared-statements.html

Comment: @Tom: I don't think it's the case for major databases.

Answer (score 1):

In my test, it escapes single quotation marks, `\r`, `\t`, `\n` and so forth. It works pretty nice:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO test(title) VALUES(?)";
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
String title = "I'm a \"student\" in a \t (university) \r\n";
stmt.setString(1, title);
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: That may be specific to your driver/db. As axtavt mentioned, most do not automatically escape input.